# How to create Native thread and communicate with main thread

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, native

I have this android project that requires communication between UI(main)thread and JNI thread.

I know how to write and invoke method from JNI but have no clue how to create a Native Thread.

Let say my java thread (main thread), at the beginning when the app triggered and the constructor being called, it will construct the button and layout and also construct a Native thread. This native thread will fire but do sleep to wait for event.

Once the user hit a button, this send signal to Native thread and Native thread will do something, return string helloworld to Main thread, for example. So I guess there has to be synchronize data.

I try to look for example but there aren't any.
some help would be appreciated. Sample code would be nice, ty.

Comment: I would not mix these things and extract only necessary parts of code to JNI and call them from Thread in Java code. Otherwise could you provide some sample code you need to make JNI thread for that?

Comment: I agree with Vladimir, creating a thread in native code is far more complex than creating it in Java. I think you should create a Java thread that receives the information that the button has been hit, sends it to the native code, and informs the main thread as soon as it receives the result from the native method.

Comment: but my c++ code is supper complicated, it is almost a program itself,all java did is feed in a number, and C++ code will go through a whole computation process and return a buffer, that's why I want C++ code to live within a thread, instead a of java code. any suggestion, I look at pthread and have no idea what they are, so i agree C++ thread is far way too ugly and complicated.

Comment: so I want to start simple, let say as soon as my app run, I will create a pthread in c++, this thread will wait on an input, let say user inputs 10, and hit a button called solve, this will wake up c++ thread and return the string helloworld 10, and if the input is 5, then it will be helloworld 5. as soon as it return such string it will go back to sleep. and this c++ thread live until my app close. IF I can get this far, the problem is basically solve.